# Group join in linq but only where childs is present

Tags: linq

I have this simple query and I want to have a list of categories and for each category the number of products inside.

```
from category in categories
join product in products
    on category.Id equals product.Category_Id into productsPerCategories
select new Categories
{
    Category = category,
    products = productsPerCategories.Count()
};
```

But if there is no products, I don't want the category to appear. With my current construct, there will be categories with no products inside. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition

```
where productsPerCategories.Any()
```

or

```
where productsPerCategories.Count() > 0
```

So your query would be:

```
from category in categories
join product in products on category.Id equals product.Category_Id into productsPerCategories
where productsPerCategories.Any()

            select new Categories
            {
                Category = category,
                products = productsPerCategories.Count()
            };
```